# Easy initialisation of empty containers

Tags: julia

Consider the following code.

```
struct MyType
    data::Dict{Int, Float64}
end

MyType() = MyType(Dict{Int, Float64}())
```

Having to repeat the type of `data` is a bit clumsy, and the problem gets out of hand very quickly if you have more variables and/or your types get more complicated. Can I avoid this?

Comment: Your struct definition has an error. The type of the field `data` should be `Dict{Int, Float64}`, not `Dict{Int, Float64}()`. The latter defines an instance, not a type.

Comment: Right, that was a typo. Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type in question is default-constructible (i.e., it has a no-args constructor), you can use the following trick.

```
struct Default; end
Base.convert(::Type{T}, ::Default) where T = T()

struct MyType
    data::Dict{Int, Float64}
end

MyType() = MyType(Default())
```

Comment: Alternatively he can define defaults in the struct members using ` Base.@kwdef struct MyType` (this macro will be exported  in the upcoming 1.9 julia version, so for Julia ,>= 1.9 `Base.` can be omitted)

Comment: Using `@kwdef` only moves where you write down your default value. It doesn't (by itself) eliminate the need to write out the type twice.

Comment: `data::Dict{Int, Float64}()` is not valid datatype definition - I guess you meant `data::Dict{Int, Float64}`

Comment: Additional question: what happens when you have more than one field? Answer: It does not work with outer constructor, yet works when you do `MyType() = new(Default())` inside the struct, however only the first field get initialized and other fields are `#undef`. Hence this code is not generic enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Base.@kwdef struct MyType
    data::Dict{Int, Float64} = Dict{Int, Float64}()
end
```

And now you can just write `MyType()`:

```
julia> MyType()
MyType(Dict{Int64, Float64}())
```

I personally more like the package Parameters which is additionally affecting how struct is displayed:

```
using Parameters 
@with_kw struct MyType
    data::Dict{Int, Float64} = Dict{Int, Float64}()
end
```

And now in REPL you can see:

```
julia> MyType()
MyType
  data: Dict{Int64, Float64}
```

Comment: Using `data::Dict{Int, Float64} = Dict()` creates a temporary `Dict{Any, Any}` which is then converted to a `Dict{Int, Float64}`. Using `data::Dict{Int, Float64} = Default()` on the other hand should have zero runtime overhead.

Comment: You are right this should have been `Dict{Int, Float64}()`

Answer (score 1):

The following hack-ish method works (as of Julia 1.8):

```
MyType() = MyType((t() for t in MyType.types)...)
```

It doesn't include `Int` or `Float64`, so it passes OP conditions. And also, it generalizes to types with many fields, and complex ones because it is essentially recursive.